# How to make element scroll with you on page?

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I would like to create an element on a website that scrolls as you scroll down the window. In most cases, I know this could easily be solved with some basic css using fixed positioning. The issue is, I would not like it to be in the same space on the screen at all times. I would like it to be a sidebar element that starts with the rest of the content, but then moves with you as you scroll down the page. See http://www.demonoid.com/ for an example (see the ad on the right side of the page). I know there is probably a fairly easy css or jquery solution, but I have not been able to think of one. I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: A always on screen advertisement? What wonderful use of the technique! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a really great tutorial to create fixed-floating elements using jQuery:

[Fixed Floating Elements | jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a

```
   if($(window).scrollTop>300) {

        $("#image").position().top($(window).scrollTop()-$(window).height());

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make it.

use `position:sticky` to get element floating.

Here is the article explained.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

[sticky position demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)