# CSS help needed for basic site

Tags: html, css

So im making a very basic website with a photo gallery, I have this css for my footer.

```
 #footer  
 {
 color: #f0c;
 font-size: 9px;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #c00;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 18px
```

And the bar does not scroll down with the rest of the page, instead scrolls up with the page like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFBei.png

Help much apreciated!

Comment: where do you want it to be? you have position: absolute so it is always at the bottom of the page

Comment: Maybe this link could help you a lot: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774882/how-to-make-element-scroll-with-you-on-page

Comment: It was good that you included what you've tried so far, and you could make it even better by including a jsfiddle or something similar demonstrating the problem. More specific description of what exactly you're trying to achieve would be helpful in future as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve from your description, and can't comment. Are you trying to keep the red bar at the bottom of the window?

In that case, the important CSS is:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

That will stick it to the bottom of the viewport (scrolling viewable area). The rest of the styling is up to you.

By the way, it would be better to use a class (`.footer`) than an ID (`#footer`) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` or `position: sticky` instead of `position: absolute` to fix something on page. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) article for more understanding how position works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then what you want is to use `position:fixed` not `position:absolute`

Fixed position will literally fix your element in place.
Here's a fiddle with it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/mSE6c/

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

**CSS:**

```
* {
margin:0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

#inhalt {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -30px;
}

#footer, #clearfooter {
height: 30px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="inahlt">Inhalt <div id="clearfooter"></div></div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

**Source:**

http://www.flashjunior.ch/school/footers/fixed_stop.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`, this will keep it in a single position.

http://jsfiddle.net/PM9Xt/ shows this while it's in action. `top:0` keeps the header at the top, while `bottom:0` keeps the footer at the bottom.